# Hibernate JoinColumn default name missing '_id'

Tags: hibernate, jpa

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn (name = "account_id")
private Account account;
```

Works fine.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn
private Account account;
```

Results in:  `Exception : Missing column account in SomeSchema.SomeOwnerTable`

JPA Spec says default join column name is

```
property name ( 'account') + '_' + target table primary key ( 'id' )
```

But it looks like hibernate is searching just the property named 'account' instead of 'account_id'.

Any comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can safely get rid of the `@JoinColumn` annotation - there's a join column anyway.

Also, make sure you haven't configured a specific naming strategy, that may override the default behaviour.

Comment: I'm using ImprovedNamingStrategy. ImprovedNamingStrategy converts, for example, Account -> account, accountId -> account_id.

Comment: ImprovedNamingStrategy was the problem. Thank you. http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/hibernate-naming-strategies-20.html

Comment: ImprovedNamingStrategy was the problem for me too. @drypot's blog post reference worked for me.

Comment: @drypot link is broken, is the article still available?