# Spring Data Hibernate JPQL Aggregate Query

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I have a Spring Data implementation with an entity

```
@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractEntity {

...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
    private Set<AccountTransaction> accountTransactions;
```

And the `AccountTransactions`

```
@Entity(name="AccountTransactions")
public class AccountTransaction extends AbstractEntity {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7045838402463741959L;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Account account;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private TransactionType transactionType;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal amount;
```

And my repository, where I'm trying to execute an aggregate query: `sum(amount)`

The result is `null` however

```
public interface AccountTransactionRepository extends
        CrudRepository<AccountTransaction, Long> {

    // @Query(value =
    // "select sum(amount) from AccountTransaction where account.id = ?1")
    @Query(value = "SELECT sum(at.amount) FROM AccountTransactions at WHERE at.account.id = :accountId")
    public BigDecimal getAccountBalance(@Param("accountId") Long accountId);
}
```

What do I need to do to get the `BigDecimal` sum of the column `amount`?

****UPDATE****

I was able to get the query to work changing it to a nativeQuery like so:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT sum(amount) FROM account_transaction WHERE account_id = :accountId", nativeQuery = true)
    public BigDecimal getAccountBalance(@Param("accountId") Long accountId);
```

This is obviously less than desirable ... as I don't want to have to write this for every query ...

Comment: I don't see any `JoinColumn` annotations to define the relationship between `Account` and `AccountTransaction` are your database columns using the appropriate defaults?

Comment: I thought the `@OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")` and `@ManyToOne(optional = false)` options took care of making the association ... so far everything else has loaded normally...

Comment: What is the name of the foreign key in `AccountTransaction`? It depends if the name uses the appropriate defaults

Comment: @KevinBowersox it should be `account_id` after it's been created in the database, and it's just `Account` in the `@Entity` annotated class...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a `JoinColumn` to establish the relationship:

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name="FOREIGN_KEY_HERE")
@JsonIgnore
private Account account;
```

Comment: So in the `hbm2ddl` statements I see `Hibernate: alter table account_transactions add constraint FK_lpcrni2dw78hajvb0gfd5xcr foreign key (account_transactions) references account` which is a randomly generated FK constraint. I added `@JoinColumn(name="AccountTransactions")` per the naming convention I set for the `AccountTransaction` entity - but it's still returning null.

Comment: Also wondering how using `improved naming strategy` (defaulted when I started `Spring Boot`) is affecting this? `account_id` is the column created on `AccountTransaction` which `mappedBy` is defaulting to see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818797/hibernate-joincolumn-default-name-missing-id (about the `JoinColumn`, states it already has one?)

Comment: Name the join column ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: thanks @KevinBowersox that worked ... capitalization!